# Looping a data extension to get the next available value

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I have a dataextension MemberDE with the following fields
MemberNumber
AlreadyUsed (set to null by default)

This DE is used to assign a MemberNumber dynamically to a customer and automatically updates the value of AlreadyUsed to Yes.

```
UpsertDE("MemberDE",1,"Member_Number",@Member_Number,"AlreadyUsed","YES")
```

Now I want to find a way to get the next available MemberNumber with AlreadyUsed = 'null'

Is this possible with the for loop?

Thanks